# isolate scope '=' not getting assigned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive:

```
CorrelatorApp.directive('correlator', function ($WebApi) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            crOptions: '=',
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var options = scope.crOptions;
        }
    }
});
```

then in my index.html I use it like this:

```
<form correlator cr-options="correlatorOptions" name="CorrelatorForm" ng-controller="PortalMerchantController">
```

and my correlatorOptions are defined in the controller:

CorrelatorApp.controller("PortalMerchantController", function

```
PortalMerchantController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.correlatorOptions = {
        dependant: {
            controller: 'PortalMerchant',
            model: 'portalMerchants',
            nameField: 'PortalsMerchantName'
        },
        principal: {
            controller: 'Merchant',
            model: 'merchants',
            nameField: 'Name'
        }
    };
});
```

when the directive links, the value of `scope.crOptions` is undefined. If I set `crOptions` to `&` and then call it (`var options = scope.crOptions()`), the code executes correctly and I get the object defined in the controller. What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: 1.2.3 has the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `ngController` directive outside of the form element.

In 1.2.0 and greater, the `ngController` and `form` have sibling scopes (previously they would have shared the isolate scope).  [Here's the change that causes this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7)

You want `form` to be a child of `ngController` so it can access it's scope:

```
<div ng-controller="PortalMerchantController">
   <form correlator cr-options="correlatorOptions" name="CorrelatorForm"></form>
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eajF/)

Comment: wonderful! thanks! btw could you recommend a good resource on angular and directives and scopes? I've yet to find documentation that isn't too complete (like the reference on angularjs.org, which makes my head spin) but explains clearly how these components interact

Comment: I found the egghead video's to be helpful:  http://egghead.io  And I also like this [video on directives](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PL53194065BA276ACA) from Angular:  .  Lastly there's a really in-depth book on directives here:  [amazon link](http://www.amazon.com/AngularJS-Directives-Alex-Vanston-ebook/dp/B00EXNI5Z2)